# Sum of binary tree not functioning as intended with recursion

Tags: python, recursion

So my problem isn't understanding how it works, but rather problems with the code. This is the code given for the class in the exam, can't be changed.

```
class Tree(object):
    def __init__(self, val, left = None, right = None):
        assert type(val) == int
        assert left == None or type(left) == Tree
        assert right == None or type(right) == Tree
        self.val = val
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
```

This class for the tree is given and my function for the sum is the following:

```
def sumTree(Tree):
    if Tree.val == 0:
        return 0
    childright = Tree.right
    childleft = Tree.left
    return sumTree(childright) + sumTree(childleft) + Tree.val
```

But it doesn't give me to correct output, why?

```
assert sumTree(None)) == 0
assert sumTree(Tree(1))) == 1
assert sumTree(Tree(1, Tree(2)))) == 3
assert sumTree(Tree(5, Tree(-1), Tree(-2)))) == 2
assert sumTree(Tree(1, Tree(2, Tree(3, Tree(4)))))) == 10
```

Should be the output, but mine is e.g.:

```
print(sumTree(0)) --> AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'val'
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: You're passing an integer to `sumTree`, so `Tree.val` makes no sense; it expects a `Tree` instance.

Comment: Why focus on `0` as a possible tree value? What is the point of `if Tree.val == 0:`? You seem to be trying to check if it is a leaf, but that comparison really has nothing to do with checking if something is a leaf. It would be as pointless as having `if Tree.val == 42: return 42`. Given that, I'm not sure how accurate it is to say "my problem isn't understanding how it works".

Comment: my idea was to have a termination condition, something like if tree only has a value and not left and rights

Comment: Hint: a leaf has no children. All nodes have a `val`, so checking if that `val` is `0` is misguided. Checking for children isn't.

Comment: 1. Don't name variable like you name the class - do `sumTree(tree)`, not `sumTree(Tree)`. 2. Your function does `tree.val`, so the `tree` needs to have `.val`. 3. Your error says it all.`sumTree(0)` - is that a `Tree` or an `int` in there? ints don't have `val` inside them. 3. Hint: look into the constructor how to determine a leaf or what to do if you go to a "child" of a leaf.

Comment: ah so in pseudocode something like if tree.right/left == 0 it should return 0?

Comment: Since the tests want `assert sumTree(None) == 0`, the function should work with empty trees. Thus, you should use `None` as the basis case (in which case, no need to explicitly check for children). Your `sumTree` should then just be 1 or 2 lines long. (for 1-line use `return 0 if ___ else ____` syntax). Also -- you need to fix the parentheses in the asserts. They don't make sense.